# Why am I receiving "Decryption Error" when retrieving channel history?

Tags: encryption, runtime-error, pubnub

I'm subscribing to several chat channels in my app. What's odd is that for each one, the callback calls both success and error methods! (log snippet below)

```
mPubnub.history(huddle.getId(), 100, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void successCallback(final String channel, final Object data) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Subscribe history success: (channel %s)", channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError pubnubError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Subscribe history error: %s (channel %s)", 
            pubnubError.getErrorString(), channel);
    }
});


successCallback : Subscribe history success: (channel f5d3fd75-6800-4c44-9d6f-93df33128c1a)
errorCallback : Subscribe history error: Decryption Error. Please contact support with error details. (channel f5d3fd75-6800-4c44-9d6f-93df33128c1a)
successCallback : Subscribe history success: (channel b655586d-df9d-45c3-9635-13ef9f8fe79a)
errorCallback : Subscribe history error: Decryption Error. Please contact support with error details. (channel b655586d-df9d-45c3-9635-13ef9f8fe79a)
successCallback : Subscribe history success: (channel e4e5a7ea-a3a5-4b69-b657-5997dbf01a37)
errorCallback : Subscribe history error: Decryption Error. Please contact support with error details. (channel e4e5a7ea-a3a5-4b69-b657-5997dbf01a37)
successCallback : Subscribe history success: (channel 2530a831-8854-4739-8e56-7e7cda31cec4)
errorCallback : Subscribe history error: Decryption Error. Please contact support with error details. (channel 2530a831-8854-4739-8e56-7e7cda31cec4)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it wasn't anything related to Pubnub.
Instead of using `Log.e(TAG,pubnubError.getErrorString())`, use `Log.e(TAG,pubnubError.toString())` and you may see the real issue.

the HistoryResponseHandler class has a

```
catch (Exception e) {
   cb.errorCallback(channel,PubnubError.getErrorObject(PubnubError.PNERROBJ_DECRYPTION_ERROR, 11, response + " : " + e.toString()));
}
```

that apparently is catching anything, including exceptions happening inside your successCallback (as in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have encryption (cipher key) enabled? It looks like its expecting encrypted data, and is unable to parse it encrypted or otherwise.  Please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'll see whats happening.

Comment: I did not intend to, we never set up encryption. How do I check in the console? I looked at Pubnub code and it appears to assume the data is encrypted by calling decryptJSonArray(), etc. Please advise.